# Systemd Ordering Cycle

Tags: systemd

I'm hoping that someone can point me in the correct direction on this.

I've got a new systemd Path Unit (see below) which is preventing the sshd.service from starting, as per the below "journalctl -u sshd" entries.

So obviously I've got something wrong, but I can't figure out what - Help! :-)

Thanks in advance

Journal:

```
Oct 10 17:08:28 host1.example.local systemd[1]: multi-user.target: Found ordering cycle on sshd.service/start
Oct 10 17:08:28 host1.example.local systemd[1]: multi-user.target: Found dependency on sshd-keygen.target/start
Oct 10 17:08:28 host1.example.local systemd[1]: multi-user.target: Found dependency on sshd-keygen@rsa.service.start
Oct 10 17:08:28 host1.example.local systemd[1]: multi-user.target: Found dependency on basic.target/start
Oct 10 17:08:28 host1.example.local systemd[1]: multi-user.target: Found dependency on paths.target/start
Oct 10 17:08:28 host1.example.local systemd[1]: multi-user.target: Found dependency on path-watch.path/start
Oct 10 17:08:28 host1.example.local systemd[1]: multi-user.target: Found dependency on multi-user.target/start
Oct 10 17:08:28 host1.example.local systemd[1]: multi-user.target: Job sshd.service/start deleted to break ordering cycle starting with multi-user.target/start
```

Path Unit File:

```
[Unit]
Description=Watch for changes (updates) to /mypath
Wants=network-online.target
After=multi-user.target

[Path] 
PathChanged=/mypath/

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Edit: Also, if this should be posted elsewhere than a simple "Hey, you might get a better answer over on XYZ list" would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I think that the nub of the problem is that [path units automatically have dependencies of type `Before=` on paths.target](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.path.html#Default%20Dependencies), so your unit is effectively configured to start *Before* `paths.target` and *After* `multi-user.target` (which is impossible, as the former is pretty early, and the latter is very late). You could try setting `DefaultDependencies=no` in the `[Unit]` section, though this seems to be frowned upon. It might be better to consider whether you really need your path unit to have the specified ordering relationship with `multi-user.target`.

Comment: Thanks - I knew I had something wrong  :-)

Answer (score 0):

From [the documentation of path units](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.path.html#Default%20Dependencies):

> #### Default Dependencies
>
> The following dependencies are added unless `DefaultDependencies=no` is set:
>
> - Path units will automatically have dependencies of type `Before=` on `paths.target`, [..]. Only path units involved with early boot or late system shutdown should disable `DefaultDependencies=` option.

So, this unit has the following ordering relations:

- `Before=paths.target`
- `After=multi-user.target`

But `multi-user.target` comes [after `basic.target`](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/blob/v254/units/multi-user.target#L15), which comes [after `paths.target`](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/blob/v254/units/basic.target#L15), which comes after this path unit, which comes after `multi-user.target`, which ….

Comment: Thanks - I knew I had something wrong  :-)